# Get higher granularity for a list while setting 0 to the corresponding element in the other list for each new point

Tags: python, list, set

I have two lists of the same size, let's say:

```
A = [100.44 , 101.05, 103.25, 103.78] # product price
B = [     20,     20,     50,     50] # quantity for the above product price (20 refers to price 100, etc)
```

I would like to be able to construct two new lists, for a given new granularity, let's say 0.2 for example:

```
A = [100.44, 100.64, 100.84, 101.04, 101.05, 101.25, etc] # higher granularity for list A
B = [    20,      0,      0,      0,     20,     0,  etc] # for each new element in list A, corresponding value in B should be set to 0
```

Remark: all numbers are 'float' type and the higher granularity I want can be anything, for example (0.1 , 0.12 ,etc).

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
def increase_granularity(A, B, size=0.2, rounding_digits=2):
    # create a dictionary that maps price to quantity
    input_dict = dict(zip(A,B))
    new_A, new_B = [], []
    # iteratively add size to price values to increase granularity between any consecutive prices
    for a_min, a_max in zip(A, A[1:]):
        while a_min < a_max:
            new_A.append(round(a_min, rounding_digits))
            # get the quantity that corresponds to a price if it exists; 0 otherwise
            new_B.append((input_dict.get(a_min, 0)))
            a_min += size
    since `zip` does not read the last item in `A`, append it manually
    new_A.append(A[-1])
    new_B.append(B[-1])
    return new_A, new_B

new_A, new_B = increase_granularity(A, B, 0.2)
```

Output:

```
>>>print(new_A)
[100.44, 100.64, 100.84, 101.04, 101.05, 101.25, 101.45, 101.65, 101.85, 102.05, 
 102.25, 102.45, 102.65, 102.85, 103.05, 103.25, 103.45, 103.65, 103.78]

>>>print(new_B)
[20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 50]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion enke !
I am getting the following error:" TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". What I haven't mentioned is that all numbers are 'float' type and that the higher granularity I want is decimal as well, for example (100.1 , 100.2 , ) etc. I will edit my question with this information.

Comment: I have tried np.arange and rounding to two decimals but list B returns only the quantity of the first price, all the values are set to 0.

Comment: @LaGabriella I edited to account for the new edit to your question. Hope it works now

Comment: working perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Since the question is edited as the list contains only float values, the previous answer will never work. Here is my edited answer. This may not be a perfect solution but you can try as an alternative.

```
import numpy as np

A = [100.44 , 101.05, 103.25, 105.78] #Modified the list with float values
B = [20, 20, 5, 50 ]

arr = np.array(A) // 1 #just for comparing with a rounded(1) array.

sequences = np.arange(min(A), max(A)) // 1 # Rounding to 1 since we need only that value to be compared
sequences = sequences.tolist() # Converting to list so that we can get the index of the element

# Now we need to find out the indices of newly added prices in the sequences array.
indices = [sequences.index(p) for p in sequences if not p in arr]

[B.insert(i, 0)  for i in indices] 
print(B)
```

Output:

```
[20, 20, 0, 5, 0, 50]
```

Comment: Hi AJITH, thanks for your suggestion.
I am getting "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". What I haven't mentioned is that all numbers are 'float' type and that the higher granularity I want is decimal as well, for example (100.1 , 100.2 , ) etc. I will edit my question with this

Comment: I have tried np.arange and rounding to two decimals but list B returns list of all none value.

Comment: @LaGabriella, I have edited the answer. Please try. It worked for me

Comment: thanks again. Do you assume here that there is only one value for each integer ?

it seems like it s not working.

for example,

A = [100.44 , 101.05, 103.25, 105.78]
B = [20, 20, 5, 50 ]
if i want a 0.5 granularity, I should get at the end
A1 = [100.44, 100.94, 101.05, ... ]
B1 = [20,      ,        0,         20,  ...]  

maybe my question was not clear enough again, I will edit later

Comment: @LaGabriella, from your example in the original question, I thought it is one value for each int

Comment: Sorry about that AJITH, I rewrote the example in my question to avoid any confusion !